# Find content of a iframe after submission of a form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Iframe whose source is a html page from the same server(cannot be accessed). Its actually a form, which is getting submitted when the user submits the details. I get a success message. 
"Project Created Successfully" and Ok button.
My requirement is that, If the result is Success, Then I should close the iframe and load the page.

Im trying to get the content of the iframe on iframe load event, and finding it like this:

var input = $(".myframe").contents().find('Project Created Successfully');

This is not working... But gets the contents of the Form(before submitted state) which has all textboxes, button etc..

I want to get the content of the submitted page.

Can someone please help me...

Thanks,
Ruth.

Comment: is your identificatoe correct ('Project Created Successfully')? is it ID or Class? You need specify it '#' or '.'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to access raw data of the iframe, then see if it matches your keywords

I would do as following :

```
if ($('.myiframe').html().match(/Project Created Successfully/).length) {
    alert('Positive result');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the load event of the iframe:

```
$("iframe").load(function(){
  var response = this.document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML;
  alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks All, How to append to body of iframe .  $(".myframe").contents().find("body").append("<input type='checkbox' name='test' id='test' value='testing' />"); This is not appending to the Form in the iframe contents. Please help. Thanks, Ruth.

Comment: Try : $(".myframe").contents().find("body").append("<input type='checkbox' name='test' id='test' value='testing' />").html();